# Best way to serve multiple WorPress sites -- Single server shared hosting

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting

I am looking to move about 500 WordPress sites from their respective individual VMs to a single server for efficiency and cost savings ..  That said --

On that single server I will have separated installs for each site.  They will have their own respective directories and will only share a common `plugins` symlink as to keep the plugins up to date across the board.

Is it safe enough to have them sitting side by side in their respective directories?

Do I need to go so far as to create a system user for each installation that only has write access to those files?

Is it safe to have the databases sitting next to each other even though they have individual usernames that ONLY have access to that DB (there is no root with "all knowing" access - `$ show databases;`).

Should I jail each installation?

Should I put each installation in a container?

I have considered WP Multisite installation, but my paranoid self can see SO many problems with that.

I have tried to research this and research and research, but keep coming up with reasons NOT to install multiple WP sites on a single server.

Should I put them behind a Cloudfare IP?

Am I making too much of this?  I have a fantastic record of no WP compromises and would like to keep it that way.

This is a self hosted dedicated VM server.  The environment is

- VCloud VMWare
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- PHP 8.1
- Apache 2.4
- MySQL  Ver 8.0.23
- Latest WordPress

Comment: Call up your web host and ask them.  They'd be in a better position to tell you what method would work best for their customers on their server(s).

Comment: @pcalkins I am using a Enterprise level VMWare host -- We are managing the OS and the server all-together.  I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: @pcalkins also worth noting .. Each Installation is on it's own VM with it's own IP .. I am looking to consolidate for ease and cost savings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked at a managed hoster where we had thousands of WordPress vhosts on one Linux server/vm. But nowadays I would include a WAF into that to protect the sites on layer 7 level.

I'm not sure what you exactly mean with putting them behind a cloudflare ip, but if you can put ddos protection and a waf using cloudflare i would definitely do that, especially if you are serving customer websites

But I wouldn't host the databases on the same server.

Make sure you have enough network bandwidth to your VMware environment and VM to be able to serve 500 sites. Also enough compute resources and so on.

I would also harden the servers with this solution.
https://github.com/konstruktoid/ansible-role-hardening

But a manager of mine always said 1=0, so for high availability purposes. I would create two VMs on different VMware hosts, and use HAProxy for example to load balance/failover, if one VM is down, all traffic is routed to the second VM. You could use glusterfs or nfs to have shared volume so the both servers have access to the same configuration files